# Show that $p\{\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n\geq M\}\geq \limsup_{n\to \infty }p\{A_n\geq A\}$

Tags: probability, limsup-and-liminf

Let $M\in\mathbb R$. How can I show that $$p\{\limsup_{n\to \infty }A_n\geq M\}\geq \limsup_{n\to \infty }p\{A_n\geq M\}\ \ \ ?$$
What I tried is $$p\{\limsup_{n\to\infty }A_n\geq M\}=p\left\{\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_n\geq M\right\}=\lim_{n\to \infty }p\left\{\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\geq M\right\}$$
but $\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_n\geq M$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_n\geq M$ doesn't has a sense... (they are probably not sets as I could consider).

Any idea ?

Comment: Dunno how the problem that this question compares sets to numbers was solved by the answer below (accepted after 5 minutes, o my...). Anyway, sticking to sets, it seems that you know that $P(\limsup A_n)=\lim x_n$ with $x_n=P(B_n)$ and $B_n=\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ and you are asking to show that $P(\limsup A_n)=\limsup y_n$ with $y_n=P(A_n)$. But this is direct since, in full generality, for every real valued sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, if $x_n\geqslant y_n$ and $(x_n)$ converges (as is the case here) then $\limsup y_n\leqslant\lim x_n$. So, in the end, everything boils down ...

Comment: ... to the inclusion $A_n\subseteq B_n$, which implies the inequality $y_n=P(A_n)\leqslant P(B_n)=x_n$, qed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: is $A_n$ a sequence of sets, which would justify the notation $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^\infty A_n$, or is $A_n$ a random variable, which would justify the notation $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}A_n\ge M$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [reverse Fatou's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma), we have

$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\Bbb{P}(A_n \geq M)
\leq \Bbb{E}( \limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ A_n \geq M \}} )
= \Bbb{P}( A_n \geq M \text{ i.o.} ) $$

But on the event $\{ A_n \geq M \text{ i.o.} \}$ we have $\limsup A_n \geq M$. Therefore the inequality follows.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by i.o. ?

Comment: @MSE, It is an abbreviation of 'infinitely often'.